# Trying to remove particular value from local storage key

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a local storage key in the form of a string. Here's how it looks :

```
var key = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(0));
console.log(key);
```

Above console prints :

```
 {"logged_user":"myname","abcDatatitle":"AHarmbca Reports","abcData":"300"};
```

Just FYI : `console.log(typeof key); prints string`

I want to remove this part `"abcDatatitle":"AHarmbca Reports"` so that the key `(console.log(key);)` would look like the following :

```
{"logged_user":"myname","abcData":"300"};
```

I could use the `replace` function of javascript like this,

```
key = key.replace("abcDatatitle","");
```

but this would remove only this `abcDatatitle` part. How can I make sure that the whole part `"abcDatatitle":"AHarmbca Reports"` is gone considering the 
fact that this value `AHarmbca Reports` is a dynamic value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: This is not an object but string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `JSON.parse` then delete the object key, then use `JSON.stringify`

```
//convert string to object
var key = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(0))
var objKey = JSON.parse(key)
delete objKey.abcDatatitle

//parse to string again
var strKey = objKey = JSON.stringify(objKey)

// update localStorage
localStorage.setItem(localStorage.key(0), strKey)
```

Comment: I have performed this step, however, when I print ` var key = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(0));`, I would see same thing again : `{"logged_user":"myname","abcDatatitle":"AHarmbca Reports","abcData":"300"};`

Answer (score 1):

You could use delete

For example

```
var myObject = {"logged_user":"myname","abcDatatitle":"AHarmbca Reports","abcData":"300"};
delete myObject.abcDatatitle
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pimboden40/eokdwr4c/7/

Comment: OP has a string. You cannot `delete` part of a string.

Comment: @sferret you cannot parse an object. JSON.parse converts a string to a Javascript Object : This is a string:  '{"prop":"val"}'. This is an object: {"prop":"val"}

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
//the key is localStorage.key(0)
localStorage.setItem(localStorage.key(0),'{"logged_user":"myname","abcDatatitle":"AHarmbca Reports","abcData":"300"}')
// we get the object data using JSON.parse(string)
obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(0)));
// we delete the property
delete obj.abcDatatitle
// we store the new object as string using JSON.stringify(json)
localStorage.setItem(localStorage.key(0),JSON.stringify(obj));
```